# Difference in passing a pointer to an array of structures to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

Is it possible to pass a pointer to an array of structures to a function? When i try this syntax, i get an error. However, if I remove the * from the function prototype and drop the & where I'm passing the structure, I do not receive an error, why is that?

```
struct Last_Payment_Date        // Date Last Payment was made by customer
{
int month;
int day;
int year;
};
struct Residence                // Residence of Customer
{
string Address;
string City;
string State;
string ZIP;
};

struct Customer                 // Customer information
{
string Name;
Residence Place;
string Telephone;
int AcctBalance;
Last_Payment_Date Date;
};

void Get_Customer_Data(Customer *[], int);      // Function prototype
void Display_Customer_Data(Customer [], int);
int main()
{
const int AMT_OF_CUSTOMERS = 2;         // Amount of customers
Customer Data[AMT_OF_CUSTOMERS];

Get_Customer_Data(&Data, AMT_OF_CUSTOMERS); // ERROR!



return 0;
}

void Get_Customer_Data(Customer *[], int n)
```

Comment: The expressions `Data` and `&Data` here are essentially equivalent.

Comment: @goodvibration - No they are not

Comment: And when you call `Display_Customer_Data` with either one of these expressions, the value of the first argument inside the function scope decays to a pointer.

Comment: I undid my close vote, because upon re-reading that duplicate wasn't good, and I couldn't find a better one.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Same memory address (i.e., runtime value) is what I meant

Comment: @goodvibration No, `&Data` won't decay to a pointer.

Comment: @goodvibration - Immaterial from the POV of the abstract machine. They have different types, which is part of the OP's misery.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Whatever. Inside the scope of function `Display_Customer_Data`, the first argument is regarded as a pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I understand approx 50% of the words in "Immaterial from the POV of the abstract machine", and approx 0% of the context between them.

Comment: @goodvibration - Whatever, stop spreading falsehoods. You are setting the OP up for failure. Your suggestion will cause a flurry of warnings they'll get used to ignoring, until it bites them in the behind one day.

Comment: @goodvibration - My sympathies.

Comment: @goodvibration Yeah well that is what the function prototype says. There's no "decay" in that context. Just type adjustment from `T[]` to `T*`. That has nothing to do with your first comment about `Data` and `&Data`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: My point is, that using `&` on a statically allocated array is pointless.

Comment: @goodvibration - Hardly pointless. But it isn't something covered in a novice text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of e.g. `&Data` is not `Customer *[]`. The type `Customer *[]` is an array of pointers to `Customer`.

The type of `&Data` is `Customer (*)[AMT_OF_CUSOTMERS]`. I.e. it's a pointer to an array of `AMT_OF_CUSTOMERS` structures.

The two types are very different.

---

The usual way to pass arrays to a function is to let the array *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

Then you would instead have

```
void Get_Customer_Data(Customer *, int);      // Function prototype
```

And just call it as

```
Get_Customer_Data(Data, AMT_OF_CUSTOMERS);
```

When using `Data` in this way, it is the same as passing `&Data[0]`.

Comment: Or `Get_Customer_Data(Customer [], int)`, which clarifies the intention of passing an array of `Customer` elements rather than a pointer to a single `Customer` element.

Comment: Another "usual" way would be the standard library iterator semi-open range way.

Comment: @goodvibration The downside of that is that some less experienced people may think it will only accept arrays. I see that as syntactic noise.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Those people will likewise think that the suggested prototype only accepts a pointer to a single element.

Comment: @goodvibration Array decay to pointer is common enough that people are likely to encounter it early on. It is also confusing. Function parameter type adjustment just adds more confusion.